# Creating an object array in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to store an array of latitudes/longitudes. I have these inputs on my page:

```
<input type="hidden" class="latitude" value="-12.3456" />
<input type="hidden" class="longitude" value="12.3456" />
<input type="hidden" class="latitude" value="98.7654" />
<input type="hidden" class="longitude" value="-98.7654" />
```

And I'm putting them into arrays like so:

```
var latitudes = $('.latitude').map(function () { return this.value; }).get();
var longitudes = $('.longitude').map(function () { return this.value; }).get();
```

But I'm thinking that it would be better to store them in a single array as objects, so that I can say:

```
$.each(array, function (i, obj) {
    alert(obj.Latitude);
    alert(obj.Longitude);
});
```

How can I modify this to create an array of objects?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would use [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/):

```
$.map(latitudes, function(lat, i) {
  return {latitude:lat, longitude:longitudes[i]};
});
```

Comment: Nice to know jQuery has a map function!

Answer (score 2):

```
var coords = [];
$.each(latitudes, function(index, value) {
    coords.push({'Latitude': value, 'Longitude': longitudes[index]});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way:

http://jsfiddle.net/95cga/

```
var longs=$(".longitude");
var lats=$(".latitude");

var objs=[];

for(var i=0;i<Math.min(longs.length,lats.length);i++){
    var obj={
        "Latitude" : longs.eq(i).val(),
        "Longitude" : lats.eq(i).val()
    }   

    objs.push(obj);
}
```

I don't like to assume things are always in matching pairs, even if they should be.  That's why the Math.min is there.